# DialogFragment lifecycle behavior

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a custom `DialogFragment` which overrides `onDismiss()` method:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    ((MyActivity) getActivity()).onDismiss();
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}
```

The problem is that this method could be executed just after `onDetach()`, which in turn would trigger a `NullPointerException`. Is there a way to safely detect a dialog dismissal before it's detached?

Comment: Have you actually observed `onDismiss()` being invoked after the `DialogFragment` is detached?  There are multiple other SO answers, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786033/dialogfragment-and-ondismiss), which use code similar to yours that users seem to be happy with, judging from the up-votes.

Comment: Are you seeing the problem when the configuration changes and the app restarts?

Comment: @qbix, I observed it when I tried to launch an activity calling the dismiss method right after that. It just seems to be detaching faster than calling `onDismiss()`, sometimes it's the opposite, though.

Answer (score 1):

I dismissed a dialog hosted in a `DialogFragment` by: (1) calling `Dialog.dismiss()`, (2) touching outside the dialog, and (3) pressing Back.  In each case, when `onDismiss()` was called, `getActivity()` was not null (i.e. the fragment was attached).  The only time when `onDismiss()` was called when the fragment was not attached was during a restart caused by a configuration change. In this case, `onDismiss()` was called for the old fragment that was being destroyed.  For this situation, you do not need to notify your activity that the dialog is dismissed, because the dialog is recreated as a result of the restart processing.  In my opinion, the code you posted, with an added check, is an acceptable and safe way to handle dialog dismiss events:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        ((MyActivity) getActivity()).onDismiss();
    }
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I came up with something similar, but it wasn't critical for my app. There could be a situation where `MyActivity.onDismiss()` should be called whenever a dialog is dismissed to obtain and store information about current stack of fragments or something similar.