# ANDROID - setOnDismissListener on a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I've got a `DialogFragment` used to display a `TimePickerDialog` when pressing a `button`, and I would like to change the text of the button to the new time set.

My problem is I can't call `setOnDismissListener` on the `DialogFragment` from my `Activity`.

**This is my DialogDragment**

```
 public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int hour = Application.getSettings().getInt("hour", 11);
        int minute = Application.getSettings().getInt("minute", 11);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        FirstTimeLaunchSettingsActivity.hours = hourOfDay;
        FirstTimeLaunchSettingsActivity.minutes = minute;

    }
}
```

And this is **how I call this DialogFragment**

```
    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

I've already thought making a `Handler` in my `activity` which would `refresh` the `Activity` every seconde, but that's not how I would like to solve the problem.

I just want, when I close my `DialogFragment`, my button to be set to the time I've entered.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DialogFragment and onDismiss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786033/dialogfragment-and-ondismiss)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the `onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)` method, which will be called when the `DialogFragment` is dismissed. You can also do it from your activity with an inline override:

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog){
            // Add your code here
        }
    };
    newFragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

Comment: Android Studio gives me a very good warning/error: Fragments should be static! Otherwise they can not be reinstanciated e.g. after orientation change... This might seem to work, but will probably lead to more issues

Comment: This was just a short example. You can make a non-inline class where you override it the same way.

Comment: @DanielZolnai In case you make it non-inline, how to you set the dismiss listener from outside of the class, namely from the fragment or activity that calls the dialogfragment?

Comment: See the other answers using `setOnDismissListener`

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way to `setOnDismissListener()` to the dialog fragment

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

YourDialogFragment dialog = new YourDialogFragment();
dialog.show(fm,"Dialog Name");

fm.executePendingTransactions();
dialog.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                       //action when dialog is dismissed goes here
                    }
                });
```

To make sure that FragmentTransaction work has been performed. We need to call

```
fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

Otherwise `NullPointerException` may occur when calling `setOnDismissListener()`.

Comment: This one works for me, but can you tell me why we need the `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()`? Without it my app just crashes. Thank you.

Comment: @SamChen It's something about view not ready kinda thing I think(if you're from web, "DOM ready"). 

In my situation, even after calling `executePendingTransactions()`, dialog is not found, which causes nullPointer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it directly inside your already implemented `onTimeSet` method. You can get the activity where the TimePicker view is embedded and update the button text

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    FirstTimeLaunchSettingsActivity.hours = hourOfDay;
    FirstTimeLaunchSettingsActivity.minutes = minute;

    YourActivityClass activity = (YourActivityClass) getActivity();
    activity.updateButton(hourOfDay + ":" + (minute<10?"0"+minute:minute));
}
```

Then, inside your activity `YourActivityClass`, you can update the button as usual:

```
public void updateButton(String newText) {
    Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonID);
    yourButton.setText(newText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't call `setOnDismissListener` on the `DialogFragment` from my
>   Activity.

You can, all you have to do is implement the interface in your activity

then Make your Activity implement `OnDismissListener`

```
public final class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        //Fragment dialog had been dismissed
    }
}
```

Then just override the onDismiss listerenr in the fragment and call the Activity.

```
public final class DialogFragmentImage extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity instanceof DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) {
            ((DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) activity).onDismiss(dialog);
        }
    }

}
```