# Retrieve value from a method declared as public void

Tags: android, picker

Hi I am new to Android and Java, and I am writing a Date Picker Fragment class which extends `DialogFragment` and implements `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` due to this I have to declare method `public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)`, in which I am setting my new date in a `public` `String` variable.

Is it possible I can use this `public String` variable in my main activity to show the value in a `TextView`? If yes How?

**My Main Activity code is:**

```
public class TARForm extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    EditText departuredate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tarform);
        departuredate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.departure_date);
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
}
```

**And** `DatePickerFragment` **Code is:**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    int selectyear, selectmonth, selectday;
    public String date;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        selectday = day;
        selectmonth = month+1;
        selectyear = year;
        date = selectday + "-" + selectmonth + "-" + selectyear;
    }
}
```

If you can guide with this information, how I can get the "date" into MainActivity departuredate? Thanks.

Comment: I am sharing the code for my Main Activity and Fragment Class. Please help.

Comment: You can use `OnDismissListener`, should check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23786151/5769824)

Comment: Use interface/callbacks

Answer (score 0):

```
    //In your actiivty
String date=null;

public void setDate(String date){
    this.date=date;
    //set this date in your text View
}


   //In your fragment

Context context;
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
    String date=//get Date over here
    ((TARForm)context).setDate(date)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain with an example, I am new to android.

Comment: Did you try the thing as i said ?

Comment: Okay lemme know then

Comment: App crashed while testing. Error: android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment DatePickerFragment{884caec #0 datePicker} did not call through to super.onAttach()

Comment: yes in onAttach(), you have to call super.onAttach() before this.context=context

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code in your fragment inside **onDateSet()** method

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        selectday = day;
        selectmonth = month+1;
        selectyear = year;
        date = selectday + "-" + selectmonth + "-" + selectyear;

        if(getActivity() instanceOf TARForm){
           ((TARForm)getActivity()).departuredate.setText(date);
        }
    }
```

and in your **TARForm** activity make `public EditText departuredate;`if your **Activity** and **Fragment** are in different folders

Comment: Updated my answer, please check

Comment: @rodaxyz Please accept the answer to close this Question